# How can I prevent WordPress from automatically writing to the .htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

The code below is automatically created in `.htaccess` by WordPress. Adding this causes some pages not work (they show a 404 not found error.) When I delete this code, the pages works fine.  However the code gets automatically rewritten in .htaccess again.

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^boot-fs\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /boot-fs.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting that code out?

Comment: "when i delete this code the pages works fine" - Are you not using "pretty permalinks"?

Comment: yes, I don't use pretty permalinks.

Comment: Is that the complete code in `.htaccess`? Are there no `# BEGIN WordPress` / `# END WordPress` comment markers? You could try adding `RewriteEngine Off` **at the very end of the file** (after the closing `</IfModule>`). Providing the code is not overwritten, this should effectively disable the preceding mod_rewrite directives (as if the code is not present/commented out). (Although knowing what/why is generating this code in the first place is really key to solving this issue.)

Comment: Are you sure this .htaccess code is for WordPress?  The front controller for WordPress uses `index.php` .  I've not seen `boot-fs.php` as part of a WordPress installation before.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting or are you running your own server or VPS where you can change the Apache web server configuration?